# htaccess: redirect from a specific link to a webpage

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've asked a similar question 5 days ago, but this one is more specific.. i hope it's ok...

someone has put a link on their webpage to my web page forum, and i want to redirect to another web page when that link is clicked...

The link could appear anywhere on their site, for the purpose of this question, let's say

```
http://www.otherwebpage.com/
```

or ir could be

```
http://www.otherwebpage.com/section1.php
```

or

```
http://www.otherwebpage.com/links.html
```

and the link is:

http://www.thelink.com/forum

So, in other words, when someone clicks on http://www.thelink.com/forum on their webpage i want to redirect to , let's say, http://www.cnn.com

i've manage to create something on my .htaccess file that works, but not as i want it to work...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.otherwebpage\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www\.cnn\.com [L]
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: What doesn't your existing rules do? They work fine for me

Comment: It doesn't redirect when a another link refering to my website is clicked on the other website... So htp://www.thelink.com/albums should be ok but htp://www.thelink.com/forum should redirect to another place.. Also, i'm not the owner of the other website...

Comment: ***"It doesn't redirect when a another link refering to my website is clicked on the other website..."*** It works for me no matter what the link is, as long as the referrer has `http://www.otherwebpage.com/
` in it

Comment: sorry english is not my first language... lets say that you have a webpage forum and someone else with another webpage is referring to your forum saying that it's the official forum and it's not.... i want for people who click on that link to be redirect to some other place, but at the same time it's ok if they clic on another link that it's not the forum... i just want to redirect when someone clicks on the forum link from this other website who's using my forum to promote he's webpage

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` file should be present in the old domain, i.e., `http://www.otherwebpage.com` and you need to add this to the `.htaccess` there:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But in your case, it is something different. You are trying to track the links I guess. So, since you are use PHP, you can do this way, before outputting the contents.

Say, a variable with a user content:

```
$content = 'Hey, <a href="http://www.praveen-kumar.com/">this</a> is my web site!';
```

And this content could be rewritten this way:

```
$content = preg_replace('\"/http\:\/\/(.*)\"', '"http://www.thelink.com/?link=$1"');
```

And this would translate into:

```
Hey, <a href="http://www.thelink.com/?link=www.praveen-kumar.com/">this</a> is my web site!
```

Comment: i have no control of the other web page where the link is... it's not my website... i am the owner of the website where the other website is referring to. i don't want the other website to refer to my website

Comment: @Marco See the second case, it answers your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> lets say that you have a webpage forum and someone else with another webpage is referring to your forum saying that it's the official forum and it's not.... i want for people who click on that link to be redirect to some other place, but at the same time it's ok if they clic on another link that it's not the forum... i just want to redirect when someone clicks on the forum link from this other website who's using my forum to promote he's webpage

You need to change the URI that you're matching against. The regex `^(.*)` matches everything.

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.otherwebpage\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum http://www\.cnn\.com [L]
```